# Parameter for function has two templated types, but only care about one

Tags: c++, templates

I am developing a workflow system to connect tasks together in a producer consumer model. The idea is you have one or more tasks that are producing and consuming data from eachother. I have implemented the tasks and now I'm trying to connect them together. To help manage these tasks, I created a connector class that effectively connects one or more producer tasks with one or more consumer tasks.

The issue is, I am templating these classes such that a `Task<T, U>` can be defined as some Task that has an input type T (consumes T) and an output type U (produces U).

I define the Task below:

```
template <class T, class U>
class Task {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<AbsData, T>::value, "T must derive from AbsData");
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<AbsData, U>::value, "U must derive from AbsData");
...
}
```

Next to connect two tasks together, I use a connector. This in a way represents an edge between two tasks. The connector has two lists: `std::list<Task<AbsData, T> *> *producerTasks;` and `std::list<Task<T, AbsData> * consumerTasks;`. What i'm trying to do is basically ignore one of the template types for a Task and sort of say I only care about the type T and want to have whatever type in the other.

```
template <class T>
class Connector {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<AbsData, T>::value, "T must derive from AbsData");
public:

 // Is it possible to set up a function so I effectively pass any parent AbsData, but hold onto type T?
 void addProducerTask(Task<AbsData, T> *producer) {
    this->producerTasks->push_front(producer);
    this->producerTaskCount = this->producerTasks->size();
    producer->setOutputConnector(this);
}

private:
    std::list<Task<AbsData, T> *> *producerTasks;
    std::list<Task<T, AbsData> * consumerTasks;
}
```

The main question is for the `addProducerTask` is it possible to pass in a Task that has some type of AbsData and type T?

Here is an example:

```
// FFTData inherits AbsData
Connector<FFTData> *connector = new Connector<FFTData>();
Task<FFTData, FFTData> *task = new Task<FFTData, FFTData>(...);
connector->addProducerTask(task);
```

This example gets the following compile-time error: `Parameter type mismatch: Class 'Task<FFTData, FFTData>' is not compatible with class 'Task<AbsData, FFTData>'`

Edit:
I have decided to rework the implementation to template the function.

```
 template <class U>
 void addProducerTask(Task<U, T> *producer) {
    incrementProducerCount();
    producer->setOutputConnector(this);
}
```

There was not a serious need to keep track of the tasks that the connector were attached to, but rather just needed to make sure the connector was added to the task, so the task can produce/consume data from the connector. Although it would be nice to be able to have a templated member variable, due to the lack of type erasure it seems like this rework was required.

This also is effective if I want to add an edge with the connector inbetween:

```
template <class Q, class R>
void addEdge(Task<Q, T> *producer, Task<T, R> *consumer) {
    producer->setOutputConnector(this);
    consumer->setInputConnector(this);

    incrementInputTaskCount();
};
```

Comment: Can `Task<T, U>` inherit from `Task<AbsData, U>` and `Task<T, AbsData>` (which should certainly be specialized) ?

Comment: Even better: `Task<T,U>` should inherit `IConsumer<T>` and `IProducer<U>`.  There's no reason that these interfaces should be specializations of `Task<,>`.

Comment: I am going to see what I can do with separating the Connector into two separate classes that a Task can use. The main component behind A Task is the ability to consume and produce data where the input data is of some type, and the output type could be transformed into a new type. Although I might have to go this route as it seems too tricky in C++ as there is no type erasure.

Comment: Can you encapsulate the consume/produce behind virtual methods?  That should maintain type safety.

Comment: That is essentially what I am doing. The virtual method in this case is a simple execute function that is passed some input type, and returns an output type.

Answer (score 1):

> This example gets the following compile-time error: Parameter type
>   mismatch: Class '`Task<FFTData, FFTData>`' is not compatible with class
>   '`Task<AbsData, FFTData>'`

That's because actual `Task<AbsData, FFTData>` and `Task<FFTData, FFTData>` are unrelated types, regardless of the relation

```
// FFTData inherits AbsData
```

of their actual first type arguments.

To fix the problem, you can e.g. make them related (if that's compatible with other parts of your design):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <list>

struct AbsData {};
struct FFTData : public AbsData{};


template <class T, class U>
class Task : public Task<AbsData, U> {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<AbsData, T>::value, 
                  "T must derive from AbsData");
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<AbsData, U>::value, 
                  "U must derive from AbsData");
};

template <class U>
class Task<AbsData, U> {};

template <class T>
class Connector {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<AbsData, T>::value, 
                  "T must derive from AbsData");
public:

 // Is it possible to set up a function so I effectively pass 
 // any parent AbsData, but hold onto type T?
 void addProducerTask(Task<AbsData, T> *producer) {
/*    this->producerTasks->push_front(producer);
    this->producerTaskCount = this->producerTasks->size();
    producer->setOutputConnector(this);*/
}

private:
    std::list<Task<AbsData, T> *> *producerTasks;
    std::list<Task<T, AbsData> *> consumerTasks;
};

int main() {
    Connector<FFTData> *connector = new Connector<FFTData>();
    Task<FFTData, FFTData> *task = new Task<FFTData, FFTData>();
    connector->addProducerTask(task);    

    return 0; 
}
```

**[live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/665746f04491f6b2) at Coliru's**

Comment: This sounds promising. Would it also be possible to represent the consumerTasks as well... Such that having a task `Task<T, AbsData> *` ? Right now I am investigating using void * pointers and using a static_cast, but this will effectively lose a lot of type safety that I was hoping to associate with these Tasks. Alternatively I could try having an ProducerConnector and ConsumerConnector class that would effectively connect the producer/consumer components of the task separately...

Comment: The method remains the same if you generalize that, but you must 'SFINAE away' (that's for B.S. :) ) what you don't need then to avoid duplicate base classes. And by all means - stay away from void-pointering that!

Comment: This is an excellent answer, but ultimately I decided to remove storing the list of producer and consumer tasks for the connector. It turns out I dont really need them. Then I templated the method to accept the additional 'whatever' type. I have editted my original post to include this.